# Start mongod instance on replica set as background job

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have setup a Mongodb replica set with 1 secondary node. When i execute on secondary

```
sudo mongod --replSet rs0 --dbpath /data --port 27017 --oplogSize 700
```

The primary and secondary nodes are linked and it works perfectly but the connection logs are running in open terminal. I would like to run the above task as background job. The option of -d doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: You need --fork and also --logpath so logs can go somewhere.

Comment: Btw, mongod --help lists and describes all available options.

Answer (score 2):

You can make `mongod` run in the background with `--fork` and you will also need to direct your logfiles somewhere with `--logpath` when you do so.  Before you go about doing all of that though, you should not run mongod as root (which you are doing by using `sudo` in the command you pasted).

Run it as a regular user, if you have installed MongoDB from one of the packages then you should have the `mongod` or `mongodb` user on the systems.  Make sure the `dbpath` (`/data`) has the appropriate permissions (as well as wherever you put your logs) and you should have no problems.  For reference, you would change the permissions on `/data` as follows (assuming a user and group of `mongod`):

```
sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /data
```